# getting data from a list sharepoint object model CSOM javascript

Tags: client-object-model, object-model

I have a list which I want to get information from using javascript. It doesn't show the list just certain things like how many items in the list.
I am completely new to sharepoint so don't have a clue how to start. Someone mentioned something about the CSOM and sharepoint object model.
How would I go about doing what I want to do?
any websites that would help me would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting items from a list using SharePoint JavaScript client object model:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Here is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, will have a read of the website and have a play around with code. Cheers